# Radiator fan only runs when aircon is on, on its own it does not and it boils and spills out

Tags: nissan, radiator, fan

I replaced a relay a couple of months back when even if the car was off it would run till the battery is flat. So now the fan doesn't run till I put aircon on.

Comment: The car is a Nissan qashqai 2007 2 lit petrol

Comment: Did you replace it with the same exact part number of relay?

Comment: Yes it was the same part number

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

Either you have the wrong relay or the car engine temperature sensor / circuit has failed.

Does the temperature gauge work correctly?

The fans should have a switch or a sensor that sends a signal to the fan control unit, so you need to test if that switch is working.

Comment: The temperature gauge works perfectly  . Tell me more about the engine temperature sensor.